# How to update a SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I've extended SurfaceView and managed to draw it in an Activity. The Activity should be able to call a method on my SurfaceView that changes some parameter and redraws it. How can that update function be implemented?

This is my class:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView
                                    implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private int circleRadius = 50;
    private SurfaceHolder sh;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet as) {
        super(context,as);
        sh = getHolder();
        sh.addCallback(this);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    }
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Canvas canvas = sh.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(100, 200, circleRadius, paint);
        sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
    public void update( newRadius ) {
        circleRadius = newRadius;
        // What more?
    }
}
```

What should `update` contain to redraw everything? Does this have to do with `surfaceChanged`?

Comment: update should be in a loop which has all your methods for changing elements on the `surface view`, also you should `lock` and `unlock` the canvas from inside this loop

Comment: I don't really understand. The update will be triggered on a button press or touch. Otherwise the SurfaceView won't change, so why should it have to be updated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The `update` function should call `invalidate()` or `postInvalidate()` in order for the View to redraw.
- Further, redrawing is disabled by default for SurfaceViews. Enable it by calling `setWillNotDraw(false)` in e.g. `surfaceCreated`.

Comment: i got it working by doing the below changes,                                           1)In the  update function called invalidate() in order for the View to redraw.
2)Enabled redrawing of surface view by calling setWillNotDraw(false) in surfaceCreated.

Comment: @dreamdeveloper How did you that. Is there something else I am missing? I did the same but it's not updating the canvas.